# Implicit vs explicit JOINs performance in Sybase

Tags: performance, join, sybase

I have seen some threads discussing implicit vs explicit joins in MS SQL Server and they all conclude they have the same performance. In your experience, is there a performance penalty either way on Sybase ASE?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer treats implicit joins the same as explicit joins, so there is no performance difference.